# Elasticsearch can't index using mongoostatic when model key is missing

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

Can't indexing model if model key value is missing in some model using mongoostatic npm,
How to fix it?

Comment: mongostatic or mongoosastic(https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoosastic) ?

Comment: Iam using  mongoosastic